Pre populate SwifData database alongside other local Entity
I have a problem with SwiftData, which is surely something simple, but I am unable to solve it .
I have a file movies.store that contains a list of about 3k movies and only has a Movie entity. The problem is that apart from that model, I have created a @Model Favorite in the app to save favorite movies. I've copied the movies.store file from bundle to document's directory, otherwise I can keep favorites between sessions. This works fine for now but I need a solution to keep favorites apart from movies, because maybe next release comes with an updates movies.store and I need to be able to replace the .store file, with no side effect to stored favorites.
My movies list could be readonly as I need it just for populate a ListView. Favorites must to be read/write. Maybe something like keeping Movie entity on movies.store file and Favorite on its own file, idk.
This is what my App class looks like. Any advice?
@main
struct MoviesApp: App {
    
    var modelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        guard let storeURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "movies", withExtension: "store") else {
            fatalError("Failed to find movies.store in app Bundle")
        }
        
        do {
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let documentDirectoryURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            let documentURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("movies.store")
            
            // Only copy the store from the bundle to the Documents directory if it doesn't exist
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: documentURL.path) {
                try fileManager.copyItem(at: storeURL, to: documentURL)
            }
                                    
            let config = ModelConfiguration(url: documentURL)
            
            return try ModelContainer(for: Movie.self Favorite.self, configurations: config)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
        .modelContainer(modelContainer)
    }
}


Sounds like the only thing that belongs in SwiftData is Favorite

I think you need to create two different ModelConfigurations.  One for the data store that holds your Movies and one for the data store that holds your favorites, then combine these when you create the ModelContainer:
var modelContainer: ModelContainer = {
    guard let storeURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "movies", withExtension: "store") else {
    fatalError("Failed to find movies.store in app Bundle")
    }
        
    do {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentDirectoryURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let documentURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("movies.store")
            
        // Only copy the store from the bundle to the Documents directory if it doesn't exist
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: documentURL.path) {
            try fileManager.copyItem(at: storeURL, to: documentURL)
        }
            
        let movieConfig = ModelConfiguration(schema: Schema([Movie.self]), url: documentURL)
            
        let favoritesConfig = ModelConfiguration(for: Favorite.self)
            
        return try ModelContainer(for: Movie.self, Favorite.self, configurations: movieConfig, favoritesConfig)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
    }
}()

The critical lines I changed are:
let movieConfig = ModelConfiguration(schema: Schema([Movie.self]), url: documentURL)
            
let favoritesConfig = ModelConfiguration(for: Favorite.self)
            
return try ModelContainer(for: Movie.self, Favorite.self, configurations: movieConfig, favoritesConfig)

You'll probably need to put some thought into, and do some testing of, how to handle relationships between favorites and movies.

You might also want to look at this question and answer which discusses what seems to be a bug in SwiftData, and has a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78530666/how-to-use-two-stores-configurations-in-swiftdata
